# MAMP Fails to Open Safari Web Page on Mac

Tags: mamp

I have installed `MAMP` V 3.5 today on Macbook Air, `OS X El Capital`, V 10.11.2  When I launch the application, the Server shows it is connected to `Apache`, but the web browser (Safari V.9) fails to open the page.  the URL reads
 http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score -1):

Safari doesn't work for me, even though it's my browser of choice.

Try Chrome, and make sure you type: `localhost:8888/`

(or whatever port number you choose, if not the default)

Hope that helps.

Tyler